# tables of eosio.token are not generated in abi file

Tags: eosio.token, table, abi

I am using "server_version_string": "v1.2.3". And I am trying to compile and customize the eosio.token contract, but the tables are `accounts` and `currency_stats` table are not generated in abi file.
How can I solve this issue? or is this is a error in this version ?